# How to pass the parameters to the webview's loaded url?

Tags: php, android, web-services, webview

http://www.insoldeals.com/.

I am doing the app for this website,
app using the  same payment gate way of the website.

How to use the website payment gate away in android app?

when I did Google, I got one solution is by using the web view we can solve this issue. When I asked the PHP developer who developed this website, he said that I was simply call the URL of payment gateway and passing the four parameters as hidden fields.

But the problem is how we can pass the parameters to the web view's URL? and how we can get the response from the web view payment is success or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
            @Override  
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
            {  
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:callMe(\""+data_val+"\")");

            }  
        });
```

Comment: Thank for your reply,i am passing parametters as hidden fields

Comment: I am not getting it. Can u give the example

Comment: this is the loaded url "https://api.secure.ebs.in/pg/ma/sale/pay/" of webview. here i am passing the accountid,reference_no,amount,description as hidden fields

Comment: Sorry i don't have idea about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78736/discussion-between-somanadh-and-prashant).

Comment: Hi please send ur value in the field :   webView.loadUrl("javascript:callMe(\""+here_add_your_fields+"\")");